# Activities in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I had a fairly simple question regarding activites in an Android application. I'm still a newbie.

In my current android application, I have about 10 activities.  If one of the activites is already far back in the activity stack, and I want to reopen it, is it okay to call:

> Intent iLogin = new Intent(this, Login.class);
>       
> startActivity(iLogin);

If it's still a little confusing, I'll give an example. The application launches with activity 1. The user then opens activity 2. Later he opens activity 3 to perform an action. After performing the action, I want the user to go back to activity 1. Is it okay to call the code above? Does it get the activity from th stack, or create a new activity? If no, how can I get the activity from the stack?

**UPDATE:** I'm interested in recycling activities, rather than creating new ones every time. For instance, not all the activities need to be created new one. Some of them only display data, which can be refreshed upon user request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to call the code above? Does it get the activity from th
>   stack, or create a new activity? If no, how can I get the activity
>   from the stack?

**Ans. If u use this code, another instance of ur 1st activity is created on the stack , And no it is not OK..**

---

ok. here is an answer based on ur example above:

I suggest u to use `startActivityForResult()` to call Activity 2 from Activity 1

here , Activity 2 will behave as sub-Activity...u can setResult and call `finish()` in 2nd Activity when it succesfully completes its task...

but before `finish()` put a boolean extra like this:

```
 i.putExtra("passed2nd", true);
```

this will indicate that the user has gone through this 2nd activity

Now, u should override, `onActivityResult()` in your 1st activity,

here  u can check the request code and retrieve boolean extra from 2nd activity..

---

**now, the important part:**
depending whether the boolean is true or not, u can decide to call 3rd activity using `startActivityForResult()` with a different requestcode,

Also, in ur `onActivityResult()` , u can again check requestcode and do what u wish when activity 3 ends

so now the control will be back to ur 1st activity when 3rd activity ends succesfully

Here is an [example](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/using-subactivities-in-android/) to get u started.

Answer (score 2):

In short: no, your code snippet will push a new instance of `Login` onto the activity stack. Please read more about the behaviour of the activity stack in the [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) article on developer.android.com.

> Because the activities in the back stack are never rearranged, if your
>   application allows users to start a particular activity from more than
>   one activity, a new instance of that activity is created and popped
>   onto the stack (rather than bringing any previous instance of the
>   activity to the top). As such, one activity in your application might
>   be instantiated multiple times (even from different tasks), as shown
>   in figure 3.

**Figure 3:**

[image: Figure 3]

A possible solution is also give there, under [Managing Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks). You can add a [flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) to the Intent specifying what Android should do in case an activity already exists on the stack. I would say `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` may be what you're looking for, but definitely have a browse through the other options as there might be one that better suits your needs.

Alternatively, if the flow in your app allows it, you could finish an activity if the user navigates aways from it. For instance, in your example: if the user navigates away from activity #2 to activity #3, finish #2. Pressing the back button from #3 will then result in activity #1 being presented, since that will then be the one on the top of the stack.

Comment: What do you recommend? Creating a new instance every time could create memory problems and the performance can also suffer. What do "big-time" applications, like Facebook do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may want to try the flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) using the [`addFlags()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags%28int%29) method of [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

This will bring the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to the top of the stack if it already exists in the stack and create a new one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you recommend? Creating a new instance every time could create memory problems and the performance can also suffer. What do "big-time" applications, like Facebook do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

`Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3` so after `Activity 3` you want to go back to `Activity 1` right? I'm assuming that you don't want `Activity 2` to still be running so you should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` so that everything in between will get closed

Comment: Could elaborate more on "everything in between will get closed"?

Comment: A -> B -> C right? A, B and C is still in the activity stack. So if you're at C then you start A with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP since A is already running it'll just rerun it and kill all the activities in between in this case it'll be B

Comment: Ohh...THat is not something I'm looking for. I'm interested more in recycling activities, rather than creating new ones.